# Wrap Windows 8/WP8 StorageFile for synchronous C++ access

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, ifstream, storagefile

I need a C++ wrapper class which can read/write/seek data synchronously from a Windows 8/WP8 Storage file (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227171):

```
class FileWrapper
{
public:
    FileWrapper(StorageFile^ file); // IRandomAccessStream or IInputStream 
                                    // are fine as input arguments too

    byte* readBytes(int bytesToRead, int &bytesGot);
    bool writeBytes(byte* data, int size);
    bool seek(int position);
}
```

The data should be read from the file on-the-fly. It should not be cached in memory and the storage file should not be copied into the app's directory where it would be accssible with standard fopen and ifstream functions.

I tried to figure out how to do this (including the Microsoft file access sample code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-access-sample-d723e597) but I am stuck with the asynchronous access of each operation. Has someone hints how to achieve this? Or is there even built in functionality?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Typically you wrap the async operations with the `create_task()` method and you can wait for the task's execution to complete by calling `task.get()` to achieve synchronicity, but IIRC this doesn't work for file access because the operations might try to return on the same thread they were executed on and if you're blocking that thread - you end up with a deadlock. I don't have time to try this, but maybe if you start on another thread - you could wait on your thread for completion like this, though it might still deadlock:

```
auto createTaskTask = create_task([]()
{
    return create_task(FileIO::ReadTextAsync(file));
}

auto readFileTask = createTaskTask.get();

try 
{ 
    String^ fileContent = readFileTask.get(); 
} 
catch(Exception^ ex) 
{ 
    ...
}
```